# Openvpn from Debian 10 to 11, stop to routing all my packets

Tags: vpn, openvpn

I had upgraded to Debian 11 from 10.
With Debian 10 openvpn works fine, now I had this problem, i can reach my vpn server, but I cannot ping or access my lan remote, except for vpn server.
This is the firewall configuration on remote side

```
iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             multiport dports 2991
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             multiport dports 2991
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http-alt
ACCEPT     tcp  --  192.168.0.0/24       anywhere             tcp dpt:cisco-sccp
ACCEPT     tcp  --  192.168.0.0/24       anywhere             tcp dpt:2004
ACCEPT     tcp  --  192.168.0.0/24       anywhere             tcp dpt:3000
ACCEPT     tcp  --  192.168.0.0/24       anywhere             tcp dpt:37890
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:2124
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:5861
ACCEPT     tcp  --  192.168.0.0/24       anywhere             tcp dpt:telnet
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpts:5900:5910
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp echo-reply
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp echo-request
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
LOGGING    all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
NFLOG      all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp echo-reply
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp echo-request

Chain LOGGING (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
NFLOG      all  --  anywhere             anywhere             nflog-prefix  "[iptables-drop]:" nflog-group 11
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
root@vpn:/etc/openvpn#
```

This is the configuration on remote side of Openvpn

```
port 2991
proto tcp
dev tun
ca /etc/openvpn/certs/keys/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/certs/keys/vpn.******.priv.crt
key /etc/openvpn/certs/keys/vpn.******.priv.key
dh /etc/openvpn/dh2048.pem
topology subnet
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist /var/log/openvpn/ipp.txt
push "route 192.168.0.0 255.255.255.0"
client-to-client
keepalive 10 120
tls-auth /etc/openvpn/certs/keys/ta.key 0
data-ciphers-fallback AES-256-CBC
user openvpn
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
status /var/log/openvpn/openvpn-status.log
verb 7
auth SHA512
tls-cipher TLS-DHE-RSA-WITH-AES-256-GCM-SHA384:TLS-DHE-RSA-WITH-AES-128-GCM-SHA256:TLS-DHE-RSA-WITH-AES-256-CBC-SHA:TLS-DHE-RSA-WITH-CAMELLIA-256-CBC-SHA:TLS-DHE-RSA-WITH-AES-128-CBC-SHA:TLS-DHE-RSA-WITH-CAMELLIA-128-CBC-SHA
auth-nocache
```

This is the configuration of openvpn in client side(the firewall is identical of remote so I avoid to post)

```
client
dev tun
proto tcp
remote ****** 2991
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
user nobody
group nobody
persist-key
persist-tun
cert /etc/openvpn/certs/keys/vpn.******.priv.crt
key /etc/openvpn/certs/keys/vpn.******.priv.key
dh /etc/openvpn/dh2048.pem
remote-cert-tls server
tls-auth /etc/openvpn/certs/ta.key 1
data-ciphers-fallback AES-256-CBC
auth SHA512
auth-nocache
topology subnet
tls-cipher TLS-DHE-RSA-WITH-AES-256-GCM-SHA384:TLS-DHE-RSA-WITH-AES-128-GCM-SHA256:TLS-DHE-RSA-WITH-AES-256-CBC-SHA:TLS-DHE-RSA-WITH-CAMELLIA-256-CBC-SHA:TLS-DHE-RSA-WITH-AES-128-CBC-SHA:TLS-DHE-RSA-WITH-CAMELLIA-128-CBC-SHA
verb 7
```

The only error i found on server is this..

```
ago 21 00:56:23 vpn ovpn-server[3791]: ******/*****:24545 GET INST BY VIRT: 192.168.0.12 [failed]
```

192.168.0.12 is the openvpn server ip, and I can reach it, but every ip in lan 192.168.0.02/24 is blocked(no ping, no ssh, nothing).

for example..

```
$ ping 192.168.0.1
PING 192.168.0.1 (192.168.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 192.168.0.1 ping statistics ---
6 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 5133ms

$ ping 192.168.0.12
PING 192.168.0.12 (192.168.0.12) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.0.12: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=166 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.12: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=164 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.12: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=84.9 ms
^C
--- 192.168.0.12 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2002ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 84.924/138.389/166.113/37.814 ms
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution found.
On Debian 11 they had a bad(imho) idea to rename the classical eth0 to a long name of 16 char! This make impossible the use of interface in iptables or bridgge-utils(the maximum network interface lenght allowed is 15) otherwise will get this error "interface name is longer than 15 characters"
So my nat goes to a non existent device(the eth0 disappeared).
But fortunately there is an easy solution:

```
vim /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules

#/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="YO:UR:MA:CA:DD:RES", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"
```

Of course replace "YO:UR:MA:CA:DD:RES"

After a reboot, i see the old good eth0 name and all return to work